# In Mysql, How do i determine the row size returned by the previous select query in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is returning multiple rowsets that are all related to one entity. The first select statement returns the core details of the main entity. It finds this entity via a `WHERE id = entityId` clause. When the value in `entityId` does not match the id of any of the stored entities I want to abort the stored procedure from executing any further.

I need a way to determine whether this select query managed to return something and i thought i could achieve this with a `IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN` statement but it turns out that i can only use `ROW_COUNT()` for `insert, update, delete` statements. For `select` it always returns -1 no matter the outcome.

My question is: What is the easiest way to determine whether the last select query returned anything? I am looking for something easier then the following:

- Do a count select before the actual select.
- insert select query in temporary table and use ROW_COUNT() to check rows returned.

I was thinking about selecting the rowset into a user defined variable first and then check whether the variable is null or contains a rowset. If it contains a rowset perform a `select` on that variable, if not abort. But i don't know if this would be best.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first select returns only one row and contains relatively small number of columns (mabye ID, Name etc) then it's easier to use local variables (`DECLARE`). Otherwise select into a temp table.

Comment: I have found out that If i create the temporary table based on the select statement I can use the function `ROW_COUNT()` to determine whether anything was returned. This is probably because MySql sees the command `create temporary table x from select * from y` as both a create table command AND an insert query. So i guess using a temporary table is the only good way to go then :)

Comment: You can also use local variables with `SELECT col INTO v_var` and check if the variable is `NULL` after the select. You can then need to use the variable in subsequent SELECTs. Saves db from creating the temp table.

Comment: I am aware of this but i have chosen for the temporary table approach because it concerns a  large amount of columns.